# Hamiltonian of a complex scalar quantum field

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, complex-numbers

Consider the Lagrangian density of a complex scalar quantum field:

$$
\mathcal{L} = (\partial_\mu\varphi^\dagger)(\partial^\mu\varphi) - m^2\varphi^\dagger\varphi
$$

With the conjugate momenta $\pi^\mu = \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\varphi)} = \partial^\mu\varphi^\dagger$ and $(\pi^\dagger)^\mu = \partial^\mu\varphi$. From this we immediately obtain the stress-energy tensor:

$$
T^{\mu\nu} = \pi^\mu\partial^\nu\varphi - g^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L} = \pi^\mu(\pi^\dagger)^\nu - g^{\mu\nu}((\partial_\mu\varphi^\dagger)(\partial^\mu\varphi) - m^2\varphi^\dagger\varphi)
$$
where $g^{\mu\nu}$ is the flat Minkowski metric, with signature $(+---)$.
We take the $(0,0)$ component of this tensor, which equals the Hamiltonian density:

$$
\mathcal{H} = \pi^0(\pi^\dagger)^0 - \partial_0\varphi^\dagger\partial^0\varphi + \nabla\varphi^\dagger\cdot\nabla\varphi + m^2\varphi^\dagger\varphi
$$

But now, according to the definitions of the conjugate momenta above, this is equal to

$$
\mathcal{H} = \pi^0(\pi^\dagger)^0 - \pi^0(\pi^\dagger)^0 + \nabla\varphi^\dagger\cdot\nabla\varphi + m^2\varphi^\dagger\varphi = \nabla\varphi^\dagger\cdot\nabla\varphi + m^2\varphi^\dagger\varphi
$$

Whereas on the exercise sheet, the Hamiltonian density is given as:

$$
\mathcal{H}=\pi^0(\pi^\dagger)^0 + \nabla\varphi^\dagger\cdot\nabla\varphi + m^2\varphi^\dagger\varphi
$$
Where did I go wrong? Is it possible that the exercise sheet is wrong? I would email the professor but I doubt he would answer over the easter holidays.
So far, I have only seen this derivation with the Lagrangian density multiplied by a factor of $1/2$, in which case the time derivatives of the field do not drop out when calculating the Hamiltonian. Also, as a personal side note, what is it with particle physicists and their abuse of index notation? Vectors and covectors are not the same, you cannot just arbitrarily shove indices around like that.

Answer (score 11):

> Where did I go wrong?

Seems like probably there are a number of different places you could have gone wrong. Since this is a homework-like question, I will answer in terms of classical field theory, and let you worry about any potential difference due to transitioning to the quantum field theory.

One potential place you went wrong is that you are seemingly not using the fact that there are two independent fields $\phi$ and $\phi^*$ (or, equivalently, the real and imaginary parts of the complex $\phi$ field). Or, you are using this fact in one of your equations and not the other.

Anyways, we have the momentum density (I will just call it $\pi$, whereas you are using the notation $\pi^0$):
$$
\pi = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot \phi}=\dot \phi^*
$$
and a second momentum density (because there are two independent fields):
$$
\pi^* = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot \phi^*} = \dot \phi\;.
$$

Thus, the Hamiltonian density is:
$$
\mathcal{H}=\pi \dot \phi + \pi^* \dot \phi^* - \mathcal{L}
$$
$$
=2|\dot \phi|^2 - \mathcal{L}
$$
$$
=2|\dot \phi|^2 - |\dot \phi|^2  + |\nabla \phi|^2 + m^2|\phi|^2 
$$
$$
=|\dot \phi|^2  + |\nabla \phi|^2 + m^2|\phi|^2 
$$
$$
=|\pi|^2 + |\nabla \phi|^2 + m^2|\phi|^2
$$

---

For two independent fields ($\phi$ and $\phi^*$), the classical expression for the stress tensor is:
$$
T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_\mu\phi}\partial^{\nu}\phi
+\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_\mu\phi^*}\partial^{\nu}\phi^*
-g^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}\;.
$$

For example:
$$
T^{00} = \pi^*\dot\phi + \pi \dot\phi^* - L = \mathcal{H}
$$

Comment: yes, thats how we derived it in the lectures as well. my issue is with deriving it from the stress tensor